# iOS uilabel text cross view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am doing a countdown apps with storyboard and navigation controller with 2 view controller

"A" controller is with UILABEL showing how many days

and "B" Controller is a date picker with button below is the code from "B" controller

```
- (IBAction)doneSetting:(id)sender
{
//Remove the time component from the datePicker.  We care only about the date
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSUInteger preservedComponents = (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit);
self.datePicker.date = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:preservedComponents fromDate:self.datePicker.date]];

//Set up a timer that calls the updateTime method every second to update the label
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

}

-(void)updateTime
{
//Get the time left until the specified date
NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);


//Update the lable with the remaining time
self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i days", days];

}
```

how do I get the countdownlabel.text to appear on "A" Controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the relation between Controller "A" and Controller "B"?

Comment: You mean storyboard relation? No relation connect I use self.navigationController pushViewController to switch between Both view.. Or you mean the relation on function, controller "B" is a setting view to set the destination date, and Controller "A" will be the view to appear how many days to destination date set in "B"

Comment: Which controller pushes the other controller?

Comment: Controller "A" push Controller "B"

Comment: How you move from B to A?  by popViewController??

Comment: Nope, no code used to return A, as I use navigationController the back button was auto added on the navigation bar on B

Comment: use delegate pattern if you want a value to go from B to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
//======= in controller B =====
Declare property in Controller "B" in .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^LabelTextUpdated)(NSString *textValue);
```

and in .m of B in your source code:

```
-(void)updateTime
{
//Get the time left until the specified date
NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);


//Update the lable with the remaining time
self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i days", days];

  if (_LabelTextUpdated) {
        _LabelTextUpdated(@"Value");
    }
}
```

//==========  And in controller "A" ===========
from where you are pushing controller "B" write this:

```
  B *object_B = YOUR_OBJECT_OF_B;
    [object_B setLabelTextUpdated:^(NSString *textValue) {
        //Here you will receive updated text 
        NSLog(@"Your Text is %@", textValue);
    }];

   //Push your B controller.
```